# SSLException: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch

Tags: android, android-studio, windows-7, windows-7-x64, sslexception

In Android Studio, when I try to update large SDKs through the SDK Manager, I keep getting the following error:

```
 SSLException: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch!
```

This always happens with large SDKs. What should I do? I have no idea about what I should do. I use Android Studio 2.2.3 and Windows 7x64. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

1. Open Android Studio
2. Select "Configure" > "Default Project Structure..."
   [image: Screenshot 1]
3. Configure "Android SDK location" and save [image: Screenshot 2]
4. Select "Configure" > "SDK Manager"
5. Go to "SDK Update Sites" and check "Force https://... sources..." [image: Screenshot 3]

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar problem.I solved it by selecting **`Force https to be fetched as http`** option under **`SDK Update Sites`** tab of SDK Manager.
By Selecting this option you can download only those packages which are having `SSLEXECPTION` Tag Mismatch error. Once you have done remember to unselect this option. For more clarification refer

[image: Reference Image]

Answer (score 1):

We fixed a similar exception in another app with disabling *Automatically detect settings* in Windows 7 with NOD32 antivirus (*Control Panel* / *Internet Properties* / *Connections* tab / *LAN settings* button).

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I just access to properties of wifi and switch enable "Set as metered connection" it worked for me.
[image: image description here]

Answer (score 1):

In my case this error came overnight and went away when I installed pending updates for Windows and the corporate Virusscanner (ESET). So in the end it also may also have been just the subsequent restart of the system.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution may be to disable your Windows firewall or Antivirus Firewall to download correctly the repositories.