# Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, windows-10, sslexception

> Has anyone encountered this error before? I'm new in flutter, is there anything wrong while running the sample file of flutter that I'm missing? The stack trace gives me 3 error like :
> ***Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch!*** and ***Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch!*** and ***Caused by: javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: Tag mismatch!***

> Here is my stacktrace

```
    Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch!
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkEOF(SSLSocketImpl.java:1533)
        at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.available(AppInputStream.java:60)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.available(BufferedInputStream.java:410)
        at sun.net.www.MeteredStream.available(MeteredStream.java:170)
        at sun.net.www.http.KeepAliveStream.close(KeepAliveStream.java:85)
        at java.io.FilterInputStream.close(FilterInputStream.java:181)  
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.close(HttpURLConnection.java:3527)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:77)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:44)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:61)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch!
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1946)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1022)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:933)
        at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:284)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
        at sun.net.www.MeteredStream.read(MeteredStream.java:134)       
        at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3454)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3447)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:62)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: Tag mismatch!
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.GaloisCounterMode.decryptFinal(GaloisCounterMode.java:592)
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.finalNoPadding(CipherCore.java:1116)
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.fillOutputBuffer(CipherCore.java:1053)
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:941)
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:491)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2376)
        at sun.security.ssl.CipherBox.decrypt(CipherBox.java:461)
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.decrypt(InputRecord.java:172)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1017)
        ... 16 more
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                         3.0s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

> the following file is "main.dart"

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {   runApp(MyApp()); }

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {   @override   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );   } }

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {   MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override   _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState(); }

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {   int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });   }

  @override   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );   } }
```

> Flutter Doctor Summary

```
PS F:\Flutter\chat_app> flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.6, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.804], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.22.6 at C:\src\flutter
    • Framework revision 9b2d32b605 (4 weeks ago), 2021-01-22 14:36:39 -0800
    • Engine revision 2f0af37152
    • Dart version 2.10.5

 
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\ShreeDivyangnaRajaji\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[!] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] VS Code (version 1.53.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\ShreeDivyangnaRajaji\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.19.0

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 5.1.1 (API 22) (emulator)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

> When I run any project, the same stack of error I face. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you :)

Comment: Can you share what code you're trying to run? It would help us help you better.

Comment: @PreetShah I share the code that I'm trying to run. But my point is, when I run any project I'm facing the same error. Thank you for reply :)..

Comment: Can you run `flutter doctor -v` and share it?

Comment: @PreetShah ok I shared flutter doctor summary check it above. Thank you for reply :)

Comment: Can you test the same on a physical device?

Comment: yes I test on a physical device I face the same error. Thank you for reply :)

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41898175/sslexception-connection-has-been-shutdown-javax-net-ssl-sslexception-tag-mism). It may be of some help.

Comment: I done it already. But doesn't work.....

Comment: I also reinstall the Android Studio, Gradle tool, VSCode, Java and also reset the environment variables. Please help with accurate solution. Thank you :)

Comment: I continuously finding solution for this stuff. Thank you :)

Comment: Shutting down and restarting my computer made the error go away for me for some reason.

Comment: @Scott please check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75334872/exception-in-thread-main-javax-net-ssl-sslexception-tag-mismatch-react-nativ

Answer (score 1):

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`
`<application ... android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" ...>`

I was facing the same problem. I just add internet permission and usesCleartextTraffic to true in app-level androidMainfest.xlm

Answer (score 0):

Try updating android studio and the corresponding flutter and dart sdks. Then go into sdk manager and update the build tools. restart your IDE and emulator and flutter should work now.

Answer (score 0):

this is gradle version error so change the gradle distrubution url
to distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by simply using a VPN !
For some reason, my local network seems to have connection issues with the targeted server.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34371284)

Answer (score -1):

I solve this problem by using my mobile data through hotspot. I think the problem is on Wifi.