# Cannot run Flutter project in Android Studio while using Android Virtual Device (AVD)

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart

I am a newbie at StackOverflow so if I made some mistakes, I am very sorry, and please correct me.

So I am currently learning Flutter in Android Studio.

Before I go on, I need to inform you that somehow my Windows 10 cannot download properly after being updated. For instance, when I am downloading UnitySetup64.exe, the download was disconnected suddenly and tells "could not download properly".

The same thing when I was downloading Unity Editor from Unity Hub (yes, I also make video games, sorry this a bit out of context, just describing what happened to me overall). So, I cannot download Unity Editor from Unity Hub.

This also affects Android Studio. I could not download SDKs etc. from Android Studio smoothly. Then, I managed to download (maybe) most of the essential kinds of stuff to develop the Flutter project in Android Studio (means I succeeded in downloading SDKs, etc.) by repeatedly trying to download things until the download reached 100%.

I also made sure that there is no trouble in Flutter, by running `flutter doctor -v`. It is said that there is no problem on Flutter at all.

However, when I tried to run my project using Android Virtual Device, the console shows this:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 arm in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch!
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:133)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:326)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:269)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:264)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:122)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1406)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readApplicationRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1371)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:958)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:290)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:351)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.MeteredStream.read(MeteredStream.java:134)
    at java.base/java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3510)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3503)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:62)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:44)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:61)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Caused by: javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: Tag mismatch!
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.GaloisCounterMode.decryptFinal(GaloisCounterMode.java:623)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.finalNoPadding(CipherCore.java:1116)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.fillOutputBuffer(CipherCore.java:1053)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:941)
    at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:491)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.CipherSpi.bufferCrypt(CipherSpi.java:779)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.CipherSpi.engineDoFinal(CipherSpi.java:730)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2497)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLCipher$T12GcmReadCipherGenerator$GcmReadCipher.decrypt(SSLCipher.java:1629)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decodeInputRecord(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:260)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:181)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:110)
    ... 17 more
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Any suggestion or help is highly appreciated since I do not know what to check or download anymore to make my project running with the AVD.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried using another Gradle version?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66300250/connection-has-been-shutdown-javax-net-ssl-sslexception-tag-mismatch
check this if it might help