# "The following SDK component was not installed: Android Emulator"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, failed-installation

I'm trying to install Android Studio, but I can't install Android Emulator. Here's what I see:

> The following SDK component was not installed:
> Android Emulator

> `javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch!`
>
> `Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK`
> `package Android Emulator: Tag mismatch!.`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SSLException: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41898175/sslexception-connection-has-been-shutdown-javax-net-ssl-sslexception-tag-mism)

Answer (score 0):

You have the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44155661/14671658

You must go to: "Default Settings"/"Appearance & Behavior"/"Android SDK" and click at the top "SDK Update Sites" and you'll see at the bottom "Force https to be fetched as http//..", check it and apply.