# javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch! ERROR IN MACBOOK M1 WHULE DOWNLOADING ANDROID STUDIO

Tags: android

I downloaded andrpoid studio(hedgehog 2023.1.1). but error is coming. javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch!  . I am new to android studio. android studio is the only software I installed. I have restarted app, redownloaded but nothing is working.

I tried to redownload android studio

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SSLException: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41898175/sslexception-connection-has-been-shutdown-javax-net-ssl-sslexception-tag-mism)